# How to specify a directory in nginx.conf to serve index.html from

Tags: nginx

I am trying to rewrite a very simple nginx.conf file.  The only purpose of this project is to have nginx serve a static index.html on localhost.

Since all of the documentation and tutorials online have minimum 50 line configurations.  I'm wondering if my 7 line configuration will work and accomplish what I need.

```
}    
  server {
    root /test/index
    listen 8888;
  }
}
```

Usually I just use the default nginx.conf and make modifications for whatever project I'm working on, so I'm not sure if I can strip out as much as I did here and have it still function?

Comment: Actually curious, did you give it a try yourself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll do best to include the server_name as well, and to end your statements with semicolons:

```
server {
    server_name some.server.name;
    listen 8888;
    # or just _ (underscore) to listen to any name
    root /test/index;
    index index.html;
}
```

Comment: also: please note that the `root` directive references a directory, not a file. So in the example above, your index file is assumed to have the following *absolute* path: `/test/index/index.html`

Comment: I don't have a server name, can I just put whatever I want there?

Comment: In that case, you can use `server_name _;`

Comment: nginx fails to start with this setup. the nginx log shows "server" directive not allowed here in nginx.conf

Comment: Then your server block is not in the right place, as nginx says. What I typed in my answer, should be the whole contents of your config. Not part of another config. Just save the file (as is) in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` as the default server.

Comment: Okay I made a new post btw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292420/why-does-nginx-fail-to-start

Comment: I currently have this config in etc/nginx/  so should I just copy the config over to the sites-enabled directory?

Comment: See my answer on the new post :-)